# Angularjs: Pictures won't load

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**UPDATE:** It works in Firefox, but not in Chrome! Any ideas???

I am following a tutorial that creates a simple list of Smartphones/Tablets with thumbnails.
http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

**The Problem:** After I did step 7, the thumbnails won't load anymore.

It actually was working the step before, but I can't figure out what I did wrong. If I call the image URLs in the URL bar directly, it works. But Angular can't do it, somehow. I don't get any errors in Chrome's JavaScript console either.

The Thumbnails are located under **/app/img/phones/** (e.g. /app/img/phones/dell-streak-7.0.jpg)

Below are the files I think of that are relevant. If you need more intel, let me know. Thanks a lot!

**/app/index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My HTML File</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

  <!-- Angular imports -->
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>

  <!-- My imports -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**/app/partials/phone-list.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
      <!--Sidebar content-->

          Search: <input ng-model="query">
      Sort by:
      <select ng-model="orderProp">
        <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
        <option value="age">Newest</option>
      </select>

    </div>
    <div class="span10">
      <!--Body content-->

      <ul class="phones">
        <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp" class="thumbnail">
          <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}" class="thumb"><img ng-src="{{phone.imageUrl}}"></a>
          <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}">{{phone.name}}</a>
          <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**/app/js/app.js**

```
'use strict';

/* App Module */
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
    'ngRoute', 
    'phonecatControllers' 
]);

phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/phones', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
                controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
            }).
            when('/phones/:phoneId', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
                controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/phones'
            });

    }
]);
```

**/app/js/controllers.js**

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.phones = data;
        })

        $scope.orderProp = 'age'
    }
]);


phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 
    function($scope, $routeParams) {
        $scope.phoneId = $routeParams.phoneId
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution.

It worked in Firefox as-is, but not in Chrome. Clearing the browsing data didn't help at all. The problem was caused by **AngularJS Batarang** in some way I don't know.

So I have **disabled** the Chrome extension **AngularJS Batarang** and it instantly worked.

See report here: https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/issues/107

Comment: I'd be interested to find out what the issue was if they resolve your Batarang ticket. it looks like a useful tool

Answer (score 3):

Try without the `{{}}` around the url in the `ng-src` attribute.

The ng-src directive takes an expression as the parameter so you don't need to use the binding syntax `{{}}`. The binding syntax basically is a way to tell angular to expect an expression.

The documentation on http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc isn't absolutely crystal clear because they use the binding syntax within the expression.

```
<img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}"/>
```

Comment: this is correct.  Anything inside an `ng-something` in angular is already an expression being evaluated and compiled by angular.  Adding the `{{}}` will stop that from happening

Comment: Yeah, I should have probably added a bit more of an explanation. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hey BenCr, I tried your solution: ```<img ng-src="phone.imageUrl">``` But it does not work. The tutorial's solution is also like I did (and it has already worked with the ```{{}}``` before I did step 7): https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/step-7/app/partials/phone-list.html

Comment: what errors are you getting if any? Have you used batarang to confirm `phone.imageUrl` exists in the scope?

Comment: Output the url in your template somewhere using {{phone.imageUrl}}. I also put window.myScopeName = $scope; as the first line of most of my controllers so I can use the chrome developer tools console to fiddle around with it and see what the values are at different times. If you add that you could see what's in the phones collection

Comment: Hi Brain, yes, I have checked the scope. And phone.imageUrl does exist in the scope. Btw, I have made an update above. It works in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Comment: It's not because the `<img/>` tag isn't self closing and doesn't have a matching `</img>` is it?

Comment: `phone` doesn't exist in the scope `phones[0].imageUrl` should

Comment: I have found the solution, see at the answer.